# Create Subsite on Get Request

Tags: site-collection, site, site-creation

I want to do the following. If a user comes to a special site collection he will be redirected to a subsite. If the subsite doesn't exist it will be created.

I know that's a creation in a GETRequest and I already tested everything from AllowUnsafeUpdates to ValidateFormDigest but nothing will create the site for me. I should be something like the MySiteHost.

Do you have an idea how doing this?

Comment: Is it like if the site does not exists, create and redirect?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what have you tried? Maybe adding some code that you have tried will help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom 404 page for your site collection, then either add code behind to it with your own logic as when you want to create a subsite and when not..

OR in SharePoint 2013 [create a custom error page](http://gokanx.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/custom-error-pages-on-sharepoint-2013/), add a content editor webpart to it, and some javscript code which will create a subsite for you, but there is a lot of things that you will require to set e.g. subsite name, url etc...

Answer (score 2):

I've stolen from the mysitehost. There the mysite is create with this mechanic:

```
 if (Page.IsPostBack)
 {
   SPLongOperation operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page);
   operation.LeadingHTML = "Meeting wird erstellt";
   operation.Begin();
   SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();

   Do site creation ...

   operation.End(currentMeeting.Url);
 }

 // This code sets an reloadAsPostBack on the site to begin site creation
 SPPageContentManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, base.GetType(), 
                      "CreateMySiteRepost", "document.forms[0].submit();");
```

When the page is loaded with GET Request then it will be posted by client code. Then you have a POST Request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the current `HTTPContext` as null, this way sharepoint does not recognise that it is a GET Request. Please see the below code, which worked for me:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        HttpContext tempContext = HttpContext.Current;//create back up of context.
                       HttpContext.Current = null;//Set current context as null
                        try
                        {

                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            SPWeb newWeb = web.Webs.Add("sitename", "sitename", "description", (uint)1033, "STS#0", false, false);
                            web.Update();
                        }
                        catch (Exception Ex)
                        {
                            lblMessge.Text = Ex.Message;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                            HttpContext.Current = tempContext;//Restore the context

                        }
                    }
                }
```